# 2D array in C not working - Runtime error

Tags: c, arrays, encryption, multidimensional-array

I'm developing a simple app to produce a Rail Fence cipher according to a text.

The application is running but when it starts, there appears a message informing me that the application stopped.

I could check where is the problem but I'm not able to solve it.

```
RailFence(char *originalText)
{
    int key = 3;
    char fenceText[3][200];
    char encryptedText[200];
    int i,j,x,y,z = 0;
    int reverseIndex = 0;
    int p = 0;

    //Fill all de 2D array with 0
    for (x = 0; x < key; x++)
    {
        for (z = 0; z < 200; z++)
        {
            fenceText[x][z] = '0';
        }
    }

    /* Fill the 2D array like a fence
        for exemple: the original text "I am very smart" with key "3" will be:

        I               e               m           
            a       v       r       s       a       t
                m               y               r
    */ 
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(originalText); j++) // <---- this block of is not working
    {
        if (reverseIndex == 0)
        {
            fenceText[i][j] = originalText[j];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
            fenceText[i][j] = originalText[j];       
        }

        if (i == 0)
        {
            reverseIndex = 0;
            i++;
        }
        else if (i == key)
        {
            reverseIndex = 1;
            i--;
        }
    }

    x = 0;
    z = 0;
    y = 0;

    /* Here I fill the encryptedText reading each line from the 2d array "fenceText".

        For example: The fence that I create above will be: "Iemavrsatmyr" 
    */
    for (x = 0; x < key; x++)
    {
        for (z = 0; z < 200; z++)
        {
            if(fenceText[x][z] != '0')
            {
                encryptedText[y] = fenceText[x][z];
                y++;
            }   
        }
    }

    //Just print the text already encrypted
    for (p = 0; p < strlen(encryptedText); p++)
    {
        printf("%c", encryptedText[p]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't initialize `i` and use as index in matrix so calling undefined behaviour

Comment: Add a check to see if originalText is null.  Strlen is undefined if handed a null pointer

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
int i,j,x,y,z = 0;
```

only initializes `z`, so your use indexing with `i` causes undefined behaviour.